# Quickblox chat data replication

Tags: quickblox

We are going to build a mobile app that will simplify a communications between our customers and our workers. Quickblox seems to be a good chose for us but we have a question:

We would like to save all text messages that are sent between customers and workers in our database. What is the best way to implement it? Is it possible to automatically add a server bot to every conversation? Is it possible to poll a Quickblox and request all conversations/messages of all users for some date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a Kafka http://kafka.apache.org integration with our Chat - each message also goes to a Kafka queue, so you can connect to Kafka and consume all messages on your side and save them to your DB for example.

This feature is available starting from Enterprise plan http://quickblox.com/plans/